# Logrus library go didn't formatted as well

Tags: go, echo, logrus

I use the logrus library for my logging purposes and my expectations are like the logs in the [documentation](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus), which are like this:
[image: Expected log]

And this is my log while using logrus :
[image: My log]

I've read through the documentation and followed the code what to do, but it still has no effect on my logs. This is the setup for the logs:

`logger.middleware.go`

```
package middleware

import (
    _ "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func MakeLogEntry(echo echo.Context) *log.Entry {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{
        FullTimestamp:   true,
        DisableColors:   true,
    })
    if echo == nil {
        return log.WithFields(
            log.Fields{
                "at": time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
            },
        )
    }

    return log.WithFields(
        log.Fields{
            "at":     time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
            "method": echo.Request().Method,
            "uri":    echo.Request().URL.String(),
            "ip":     echo.Request().RemoteAddr,
        },
    )
}

func LoggingRequest(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        MakeLogEntry(c).Info("Incoming request")

        return next(c)
    }
}

func ErrorHandler(err error, c echo.Context) {
    report, ok := err.(*echo.HTTPError)
    if ok {
        report.Message = map[string]interface{}{
            "error":       "HTTP Error",
            "message":     report.Message,
            "status code": report.Code,
        }
    } else {
        report = echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    }

    MakeLogEntry(c).Error(report.Message)

    c.JSON(report.Code, report.Message.(map[string]interface{}))
}
```

Is there a setting I'm missing? or is there any code that should be added?

Comment: Could you please add some more information - what is your expectation? For example: Do you want the logs to be colored? Do you want the output to start with "INFO[0000]"?

Comment: Yes! something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print log as the first picture with colorized log level, you just have to remove the block

```golang
log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{
        FullTimestamp:   true,
        DisableColors:   true,
    })
```

it's clear that you are using the `TextFormatter` which is not the default log format for logrus

Or if you want to segregate the color by log level, try to set `DisableColors` to `false`

Should you find my solution useful, please do upvote

Comment: I've tried that and it's still the same

Comment: try removing only `DisableColors: true`. and try run it

Comment: Nothing change...